# pass event to eventhandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I'm still confused sometimes by the way events are handled. I just wondered how to pass the event to it's handler.

The following example just works fine:

```
$(document).on('click', "div#foo", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

But how to pass the event to an handler specified by name, like:

```
// this obviously wont work
$('div#foo').on('click', fooClick);
function fooClick(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is exactly how to do it and that will work just fine.

It is the responsibility of `.on()` to set up the arguments to the callback it calls and what is passes has absolutely nothing to do with how you declare your callback.  The first argument to the callback function will be the `event` object no matter how the callback is declared.

So, this will work just fine:

```
function fooClick(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}

// this works just fine
$('div#foo').on('click', fooClick);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BWKde/

What's important to understand is that when you pass `fooClick` as the second argument to `.on()`, you are just passing a function reference.  It is `.on()` who decides how to call that function reference and what to pass it.

---

FYI, your selectors will generally perform better if you pass just `#foo`, not `div#foo` unless you specifically want to only match `#foo` if it's in a `div` tag.  Since id values can only be used once in a given page, you usually don't need to qualify them further and doing so just makes more (unnecessary) work for the selector engine.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Still it seems not to work for me. I use the preventDefault on a link, and if I use the way described in the second example, it opens the link in a new window.

Comment: @nevrx - Can you reduce it to a small demo in jsFiddle because the concept is correct so there must be something else wrong with your implementation.

Comment: @nevrx - I added a working demo to show you that the concept works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BWKde/

Comment: I just did, and it works.. unfortuantly, because I can't get it running on my site, which is pretty odd. 
So, thanks for confirming, that I wasn't that wrong in the end. I'll try to figure out the oddness tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

your code is ok,

check at http://jsfiddle.net/9266U/ and read more at https://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('div#foo').on('click', fooClick);
function fooClick(e){
    alert("it work, nevrx");
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I can only check one answer as correct, yours is too.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is synchronous, try to put it like this:

```
function fooClick(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
$('div#foo').on('click', fooClick);
```